# Shrink text (font-size) to fit in placeholder of an input tag

Tags: html, css

**IMPORTANT**: Please continue reading below the snippet code.

I am using input boxes and I have a text in the placeholder of them. I want the **text to shrink** in order to fit in the div. But it seems that my string is being cut off:

[image]

I used `font-size:1vw;` in the CSS but it does not work. So, now I am using a JS code. But it works only if I use a div that has the same content as the one I use in the placeholder.

```js
var divWidth = $('.theDiv').width();
var text = $('.text');
var fontSize = 12;

while (text.width() > divWidth)
  text.css('font-size', fontSize -= 0.5);

text.css('display', 'inline');
```

```css
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Lato Light'), local('Lato-Light'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/dPJ5r9gl3kK6ijoeP1IRsvY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Lato Light'), local('Lato-Light'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/EsvMC5un3kjyUhB9ZEPPwg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}


body {
    background: hsl(184,65%,49%);
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
 
}

input[type="text"], .theDiv {
 width:100%;
 max-width:320px;
 background:#fff;
 color:#333;
    font-family: Lato;
    padding: 25px 15px 25px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    border: 3px solid #333;
}

.theDiv{
   white-space:nowrap;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  text-align:center;
   white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="theDiv">
  <span class="text" style="display:none;">This sentence is too large to fit within the div. This sentence is too large to fit within the div his sentence is too large to fit within the div his sentence is too large to fit within the div</span>
</div>


<input class="text" type="text" placeholder="This sentence is too large to fit within the div. This sentence is too large to fit within the div his sentence is too large to fit within the div his sentence is too large to fit within the div" />
```

This is the line where I have the issue :

```
 var divWidth = $('.theDiv').width();
```

So, instead of getting the width of the `div`, I want to have ONLY the `input` tag in my code and get the width of the `input` tag in the JS. I tried :

```
var divWidth = $(input).width();
```

with no success.

Comment: Pretty sure you'd need JavaScript for this

Comment: @j08691 It works for all the tags. Why isn't that working for the placeholder of the input? I was not able to find a similar question.

Comment: You set size of input in pixels and font size in vw - try to resize your browser and you will see that your text size depends on browser's width, so in some cases it will be too small, and in some -- too big.
To fit text I use 'fittextjs' but I didn't try it with inputs, only with divs.
Or try to set input's width in vw units too, so both input and text will depend on browser's width so they will keep ratio

Comment: @YuriGor I ll try that and come back

Comment: @YuriGor I updated the question